# How can I suppress 128 bit floats in the llvm data layout?

Tags: build, llvm

I'm linking two modules together (in KLEE, but that isn't important, I think) and llvm complains because they seem to have different data layouts:

> WARNING: Linking two modules of different data layouts!

I had a look at those and it turns out the first `libkleeRuntimeIntrinsic.bca` has the following layout

```
e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64
```

while my own `client.bc` has

```
e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-f128:128:128-n8:16:32:64
```

I compared these and the latter has a `f128:128:128` too much, which according to [the documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#datalayout) indicates support for 128 bit floats.

These were built on the very same system with the same version of `llvm-gcc` and linked/archieved with `llvm-ld`/`llvm-ar`. All llvm version 2.9 (my llvm is configured in `Debug+Asserts` mode).

What is the reason for this, and how can I get the second (`client.bc`) to have the same daya layout (that is, without the `f128:128:128`)?

Comment: What OSes do you have on each system?

Comment: @vkorchagin: There is only one system, which is a `GNU/Linux 2.6.38-15-generic x86_64`.

Comment: I saw something similar, also when using KLEE. In my case, I had compiled my own client bitcode using `clang`, while KLEE's supporting bitcode had used `llvm-gcc`. Bitcode from clang omitted `f128:128:128`, but bitcode from `llvm-gcc` included it. I know you said you used the same `llvm-gcc` for both, which is why I offer this as a comment and not a possible answer. Perhaps it helps anyway.